# Convert XML to dictionary in Python using lxml

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

There seem to be lots of solutions on StackOverflow for converting XML to a Python dictionary, but none of them generate the output I'm looking for.  I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<status xmlns:mystatus="http://localhost/mystatus">
<section1
    mystatus:field1="data1"
    mystatus:field2="data2" />
<section2
    mystatus:lineA="outputA"
    mystatus:lineB="outputB" />
</status>
```

[lxml has an elegantly simple solution](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#how-can-i-map-an-xml-tree-into-a-dict-of-dicts) for converting XML to a dictionary:

```
def recursive_dict(element):
 return element.tag, dict(map(recursive_dict, element)) or element.text
```

Unfortunately, I get:

```
('status', {'section2': None, 'section1': None})
```

instead of:

```
('status', {'section2': 
                       {'field1':'data1','field2':'data2'}, 
            'section1': 
                       {'lineA':'outputA','lineB':'outputB'}
            })
```

I can't figure out how to get my desired output without greatly complicating the recursive_dict() function.

I'm not tied to lxml, and I'm also fine with a different organization of the dictionary, as long as it gives me all the info in the xml.  Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you expect to get the attributes of sections, but not the attributes of the status?  What magic lets the library know that's what you want?   And ... is there some reason why the contents of sections are attributes and not elements?

Comment: The XML comes from a source I don't control.  I need to be able to consume it and act on it. That's why I said I'd be "fine with a different organization of the dictionary".  My objective is to get all the information--be it tag, text, attribute, whatever--into a simple structure like a dictionary.  No "magic" needed.  Values of "None" are fine.  I just want ALL the info in the XML captured.

Comment: It sounds like you have a solution, but I just want to note that the desired output you showed does not show _ALL_ the information captured.  It shows the attributes of sections captured, but not the attributes of status.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Personally I like `xmltodict` from [here](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict).  With pip you can install it like so `pip install xmltodict`.

Note that this actually creates `OrderedDict` objects.  Example usage:

```
import xmltodict as xd

with open('test.xml','r') as f:
    d = xd.parse(f)
```

Comment: Although I'd prefer to not need to install anything extra, this is very simple and looks like it will work so I'll give a try.  Thanks!

Comment: This works great!  I prefer to reformat it with d=ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(d)) after the parse but the default output preserves everything perfect for me!  Thanks!

Comment: Be aware of xmltodict when working with big xmls. 
xmltodict is using python xml module from standard library. It becomes very slow when xml > 1 GB. Instead use lxml

Comment: It also randomly does not convert stuff to #text like here https://dd.weather.gc.ca/citypage_weather/xml/ON/s0000022_e.xml the condition is None? and IconName does not have the icon name #text

Comment: Had to change 
open('test.xml','r') to
open('test.xml','rb')

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jacobian/795571

```
def elem2dict(node):
    """
    Convert an lxml.etree node tree into a dict.
    """
    result = {}

    for element in node.iterchildren():
        # Remove namespace prefix
        key = element.tag.split('}')[1] if '}' in element.tag else element.tag

        # Process element as tree element if the inner XML contains non-whitespace content
        if element.text and element.text.strip():
            value = element.text
        else:
            value = elem2dict(element)
        if key in result:

            
            if type(result[key]) is list:
                result[key].append(value)
            else:
                tempvalue = result[key].copy()
                result[key] = [tempvalue, value]
        else:
            result[key] = value
    return result
```